# Katello Installation failing wget

Tags: centos, centos7, foreman

Im trying to install Katello on CentOS 7

I get the following error:

```
# foreman-installer --scenario katello --katello-proxy-url http://proxy.domain.com --katello-proxy-port 8080 --foreman-admin-username admin --foreman-admin-password test123!
/usr/bin/wget --no-proxy --timeout=30 --tries=40 --wait=20 --retry-connrefused -qO- http://localhost:8080/candlepin/admin/init > /var/log/candlepin/cpinit.log 2>&1 && touch /var/lib/candlepin/cpinit_done returned 8 instead of one of [0]
```

Can anyone confirm or solve?

kind regards